# Binary search on real space

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I want to perform a binary search on a continuous [unimodal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodality#Unimodal_function) function *ƒ(x)=y*, where *x* and *y* are real numbers. I'm not looking up values in an array, and so I don't have clean integer inputs that I'm stepping along.

My original attempt at a function (written in JavaScript) has the problem that when the input value you are looking for happens to sit on a boundary chosen by the algorithm, the algorithm continues to run until the numeric precision is exhausted:

```
/**
 * y: the target output value to find a matching input
 * minX: the smallest input value
 * maxX: the largest input value
 * ƒ:    a function that returns a value given an X
 * ε:    the threshold to compare outputs versus the target (default:0)
 */
function binarySearch(y, minX, maxX, ƒ, ε) {
    if (ε===undefined) ε=0;
    let m=minX, n=maxX, k, v, Δ;
    while (m<=n) {
        k = (n+m)/2;
        v = ƒ(k);
        Δ = y-v;
        if (Math.abs(Δ)<=ε) return k;
        if (Δ>0) m = k;
        else     n = k;
    }
    if (Math.abs(y-ƒ(m))<=ε) return m;
    if (Math.abs(y-ƒ(n))<=ε) return n;
}
```

With the above, the call `binarySearch( 0, 0, 10, n=>n )` will run 1077 iterations until `m=0` and `n=5e-324` before *(m+n)/2* is finally so close to 0 that even with `ε=0` the JavaScript interpreter cannot tell the difference.

A hack I was going to use is to provide a minimum step function that modifies each boundary by a fixed amount (similar to array index +/- 1). This forces the boundary to move faster, but also requires an `ε>0` in case the boundary overshoots the value. It feels gross:

```
// step: a minimum amount to move each boundary each time
function binarySearch(y, minX, maxX, ƒ, ε, step) {
    if (ε===undefined) ε=0;
    if (step===undefined) step=0;
    let m=minX, n=maxX, k, v, Δ;
    while (m<=n) {
        k = (n+m)/2;
        v = ƒ(k);
        Δ = y-v;
        if (Math.abs(Δ)<=ε) return k;
        if (Δ>0) m = k+step;
                 n = k-step;
    }
    if (Math.abs(y-ƒ(m))<=ε) return m;
    if (Math.abs(y-ƒ(n))<=ε) return n;
}
```

A ~clean fix is to check the boundaries on every pass by moving the final two `if` statements into the `while` loop. This calls `ƒ()` three times as often each pass, and so seems inelegant.

```
/**
 * y: the target output value to find a matching input
 * minX: the smallest input value
 * maxX: the largest input value
 * ƒ:    a function that returns a value given an X
 * ε:    the threshold to compare outputs versus the target (default:0)
 */
function binarySearch(y, minX, maxX, ƒ, ε) {
    if (ε===undefined) ε=0;
    let m=minX, n=maxX, k, v, Δ;
    while (m<=n) {
        k = (n+m)/2;
        v = ƒ(k);
        Δ = y-v;
        if (Math.abs(y-ƒ(m))<=ε) return m;
        if (Math.abs(y-ƒ(n))<=ε) return n;
        if (Math.abs(Δ)<=ε) return k;
        if (Δ>0) m = k;
        else     n = k;
    }
}
```

It smells to me like there ought to be an elegant solution, some sort of fencepost I'm not thinking of, that fixes this efficiently and elegantly.

Comment: I'd just like to point out something possibly obvious: While using non-ASCII characters for variable names does look good, it can be confusing for some people, and difficult to edit for most developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize now that the only time this is a problem is when the value I'm looking for is either of the starting boundaries. In all other cases, a boundary is only moved after it is checked.

So, all I had to do was check both boundaries once, before the loop starts. A fixed, slightly terser version of the original function:

```
/**
 * y: the target output value to find a matching input
 * minX: the smallest input value
 * maxX: the largest input value
 * ƒ:    a function that returns a value `y` given an `x`
 * ε:    the threshold to compare outputs versus the target (default:0)
 */
function binarySearch(y, minX, maxX, ƒ, ε) {
    if (ε===undefined) ε=0;
    let m=minX, n=maxX, k, Δ;
    if (Math.abs(y-ƒ(m))<=ε) return m;
    if (Math.abs(y-ƒ(n))<=ε) return n;
    while (m<n) {
        Δ = y - ƒ( k = (n+m)/2 );
        if (Math.abs(Δ)<=ε) return k;
        if (Δ>0) m=k;
        else     n=k;
    }
}
```

*Note that this function also fixes a ~bug in the while loop by changing the condition to `m<n` instead of `m<=n`.*

Answer (score 0):

Something to consider is that the computer representation of the real field is not uniform.  Half of all the possible unique values for a float (or double) occur in the interval 1 to -1.  This usually doesn't cause a problem, but if your algorithm can choose a value close to the max or min values it can produce surprises.

I suspect the reason your initial implementation had problems was that your calculations were getting jitter in the lowest bit positions.